# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in Flask, mysql application

Tags: python, mysql, flask, jwt

I am creating a login application using Flask-mysql.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, json
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from datetime import datetime
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_jwt_extended import (create_access_token, create_refresh_token, jwt_required, jwt_refresh_token_required, get_jwt_identity, get_raw_jwt)
import yaml

app = Flask(__name__)
alogin = yaml.load(open('alogin.yaml'))
app.config['MYSQL_HOST']= alogin['mysql_host']
app.config['MYSQL_USER']= alogin['mysql_user']
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD']= alogin['mysql_password']
app.config['MYSQL_DB']= alogin['mysql_db']
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'

mysql = MySQL(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
jwt = JWTManager(app)

CORS(app)

@app.route('/alogin', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    email = request.get_json()['email']
    password = request.get_json()['password']
    result = ""
    
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM admin where email = '" + str(email) + "'")
    rv = cur.fetchone()
    
    if bcrypt.check_password_hash(rv['password'], password):
        access_token = create_access_token(identity = {'id':rv['id'],'email': rv['email']})
        result = jsonify({"token":access_token})
    else:
        result = jsonify({"error":"Invalid username and password"})
    
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am getting the the error as follows:

```
if bcrypt.check_password_hash(rv['password'], password):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I have tried using 'force=True' in

```
    email = request.get_json(force = True)['email']
    password = request.get_json(force = True)['password']
```

Yet it is throwing the same error.
This is my first application with flask. Help will be appreciated.

PS : admin is the name of the table in the database and I have already created it in the mysql database.

Comment: What if my email is `'; DROP TABLE admin --`?

Comment: And while the above is annoying, a more insidious user would send something like `"notfound' UNION SELECT 1 AS id, CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(email SEPARATOR ','), ';', GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(password USING latin1) SEPARATOR ',')) AS email, X'<attacker-chosen-bcrypt-hash>' AS password FROM admin -- "@foo.bar` to collect all your admin credentials – or anything from your DB for that matter, they could read from any which table they want. The moral of the story is: use placeholders in your query and pass the values to `execute()` separately.

Answer (score 2):

`fetchone()` will return `None` if the query doesn't result in data. Add an

```
if rv is None:
```

check to handle the case of someone providing an email address that isn't in the database.

Also, take a moment and look up "SQL Injection Attack".